# Использование командной строки для выполнеия действий с аргументами строки Java

Tags: java, парсер, командная-строка

Я разрабатываю приложение коммандной строки, где в строку вводится информация так: --file=example.txt add --name=John --surname=Doe --age=22 --email=example@example.com. Создан класс модели (ну, скажем - Person) с соответствующими полями, геттерами, toString() и пр., Интерфейс с методом, выполняющим любую команду - execute(Map global, Map local) и Классы для каждой команды, имплементирующие описанный выше интерфейс и содержащие логику для выполнения каждой команды. Парсинг командной строки и выполнение каждой команды делается так:

```
public class Parser {

public void start(String[] args) throws RuntimeException {
    Map<String, String> globalOptions = new Parser().cmdParser(args);
    Map<String, String> localOptions = new Parser().cmdParser(args);

    for (String arg : args) {
        switch (arg) {
            case "add":
            case "a":
                AddCommand add = new AddCommand();
                add.execute(globalOptions, localOptions);
                break;
            case "view":
            case "v":
                ViewAllCommand view = new ViewAllCommand();
                view.execute(globalOptions, localOptions);
                break;
            case "replace":
            case "r":
                ReplaceCommand rc = new ReplaceCommand();
                rc.execute(globalOptions, localOptions);
                break;
            case "find":
            case "f":
                FindCommand fc = new FindCommand();
                fc.execute(globalOptions, localOptions);
                break;
            case "clear":
            case "c":
                ClearCommand cc = new ClearCommand();
                cc.execute(globalOptions, localOptions);
                break;
            case "help":
            case "h":
                HelpCommand hc = new HelpCommand();
                hc.execute(globalOptions, localOptions);
        }
    }
}

private Map<String, String> cmdParser(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> arguments = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String key;
    String value;
    int index;

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (args[i].startsWith("--")) {
            key = args[i].substring(2);
        } else if(args[i].startsWith("-")) {
            key = args[i].substring(1);
        } else {
            arguments.put(args[i], null);
            continue;
        }

        index = key.indexOf('=');

        if(index == -1) {
            if((i + 1) < args.length) {
                if(args[i + 1].charAt(0) != '-') {
                    arguments.put(key, args[i + 1]);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    arguments.put(args[i], null);
                }
            } else {
                arguments.put(args[i], null);
            }
        } else {
            value = key.substring(index + 1);
            key = key.substring(0, index);
            arguments.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    return arguments;
}}
```

Вопрос в следующем - можно ли было бы как-то "избавиться" от блока swith() и, для большей гибкости и универсальности приложения, использовать какойто другой подход для решения этой задачи?

Вот, как я "пробегаюсь" по Map<>:

```
 Map<String, Class> commands = new HashMap<>();
    Class add = AddCommand.class;
    Class clear = ClearCommand.class;
    Class find = FindCommand.class;
    Class help = HelpCommand.class;
    Class replace = ReplaceCommand.class;
    Class view = ViewAllCommand.class;
    commands.put("add", add);
    commands.put("clear", clear);
    commands.put("find", find);
    commands.put("replace", replace);
    commands.put("view", view);
    commands.put("help", help);

    for (String key : commands.keySet()) {
        Command command = null;
        key = args[i + 1];
        try {
            command = (Command) commands.get(key).getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert command != null;
        command.execute(globalOptions, localOptions);
    }
```

Comment: Можно попробовать связать строку с именем класс, например через энум или мапу. и минуя свитч создавать экземпляр этого класса и вызывать нужный метод.
`ReplaceCommand rc = new ReplaceCommand();` надо только поправить на `InterfaceNameCommand = new ReplaceCommand()`

Comment: @ Maxim О! Возможно такое и сработает. А, если не сложно, можно несколько подробнее, через мапу, например...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно создавать по команде новый объект и вызывать у него метод `.execute(globalOptions, localOptions)`?

Вы можете сделать карту `параметр: класс` типа:

```
find: FindCommand.class()
f:    FindCommand.class()
```

Плюс в том что карта не захардкодена, вы можете ее создавать, получать, хранить, изменять, не меняя при этом код приложения.

Получая параметр из строки проходиться по карте, если ключ в карте присутствует - создавать объект нужного класса  и вызывать у него метод `.execute(globalOptions, localOptions)`.

Мне было  ̶л̶е̶н̶ь̶  (другая важная причина) создавать интерфейс и реализующие классы, поэтому пример получился с `Object` вместо интерфейса, объектом класса `String` вместо класса реализующего интерфейс. А сам интерфейс как бы `.getClass().getSimpleName()` вместо `.execute()`.

```
    Map <String, Class> objects = new HashMap<>();
    Class str = String.class;

    objects.put("i need a string", str);  //запись в карте параметр: класс

    Object obj = null;
    try {
        // создаем экземпляр объекта по параметру
        obj = objects.get("i need a string").getConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // вызываем у объекта нужный нам метод
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Тем не менее мы можем положить в карту класс нужного нам объекта, имея ключ пройтись по карте, вынуть из карты класс, сконструировать нужный нам объект и вызвать у него метод.

Comment: Спасибо! По моему, очень изящное решение!

Comment: У меня не получается перебрать Map<> правильно, что-то делаю не так... Может быть сможете подсказать, в чем ошибаюсь?..

Comment: Карту перебирать в принципе не надо, она сразу дает ответ по ключу. Попробуйте посмотреть что дает карта `System.out.println(mapname.get(key));`. Если ничего - значит ключи не совпадают, возможно в ключе из консоли есть невидимый символ переноса или т.п.

Comment: Да, Вы абсолютно правы. Действительно мапу перебирать не нужно, все и так ОК. Это я чего-то "торможу". Еще раз огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй эту либу: **Apache Commons CLI**

Сам не пользовался, но выглядит достаточно простой. Вот [get started](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html)

```
// Создаем объект, в котором определяем параметры
Options options = new Options();

// Добавляем один из них (имя, нужно ли указывать значение или это просто флаг, описание)
options.addOption("t", false, "display current time");

//Парсим входные параметры
CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);

//Указан ли такой параметр (флаг)
cmd.hasOption("t");
//Получить значение параметра
cmd.getOptionValue("c");
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, про эту библиотеку я знаю... И с ней уже работал. Но, в данном случае, нужно сделать "вручную". Commons CLI не потокобезопасна и подобные библиотеки не хотят использовать...(